# cloudant node module - Unable to search with index

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

**I'm trying to list the indexes, but the call fails with an exception.**

```
db = cloudant.db.use(dbName);

db.index(function(er, result) {
  if (er) {
    throw er;
  }
// ...
}
```

**Find call also fails with the same exception.**

```
db.find(params, function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('#### ' + error);
  }
//...
}
```

Error: **

> Only DELETE,GET,HEAD,PUT allowed`
>
> **
>       at Request._callback (.../node_modules/cloudant/node_modules/nano/lib/nano.js:248:15)
>       at Request.self.callback (.../node_modules/cloudant/node_modules/nano/node_modules/request/request.js:200:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at Request. (.../node_modules/cloudant/node_modules/nano/node_modules/request/request.js:1046:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (.../node_modules/cloudant/node_modules/nano/node_modules/request/request.js:973:12)
>       at emitNone (events.js:72:20)

Appreciate your help getting through this, thank you very much.

Comment: My bad, there was a '/' at the end of the Cloudant URL which was causing the Cloudant special functions to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means either:
- you are using a wrong/unexpected HTTP method (POST in this case?)
- a wrong URL which is responding but obviously it is not expecting the request received

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I turned on detailed logging for Cloudant and Nano modules, and figured out that the extra '/' at the end of the URL was causing the issue.  I could verify this by trying it directly on the browser.

Comment: Thank you. If you found it useful, please accept the answer